# Database user model for social login

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-connection

I would want to implement social login via Facebook & Google.

I have divided it into 3 models: users, userProfiles & authenticationProviders..

Both userProfiles & authProviders link 1:1 to user.
Since I would like to implement option that user can login via Google or he can create account manually by providing email & password

Is this a good practice or is there some other preferred way how this is done ?

Here are my models

**Users**

```
CREATE TABLE users(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        name TEXT,
        screenname TEXT,
        created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
      )
```

**Users Profile**

```
CREATE TABLE userProfile(
        email TEXT,
        password TEXT,
        created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        user_id INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
      )
```

**AuthenticationProvider**

```
CREATE TYPE providerType AS ENUM ('google', 'facebook');
CREATE TABLE authenticationProviders (
    providerKey varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    providerType providerType,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    user_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
  )
```

Comment: Asking for "other ways" is not a valid SO question. Also what is your own attempt to answer this? What is your research re applying "best practice" here? What design reference are you stuck following? See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS "link 1:1 to user" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. We can guess that you mean that a user_id has to be a user id & vice versa. But you only declare that a user_id is an id. PS SQL difficulties with such "1:1" tables with FKs both ways is a faq.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is "this"? (You just say a bunch of things you're doing with a bit of reasoning.) Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook.If you're not sure it's right, ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re where you got stuck.

Comment: @philipxy Yes I got this wrong, I was searching like for opinion is this table design ok ? I'm trying to code website with social login, in this is how I structure my tables, so I'm asking is this alright or are there some issues ?